# Do Dockerfile RUN commands run in a login shell environment?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Or, in other words, do I need to run `docker run -it <container> bash` or `docker run -it <container> bash --login` to get the same environment as what they would run in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> to get the same environment as what they would run in?

I understand "As they would run *by default without specfifying a command*"

That will simply depend on how your container is actually configured to run:

- if the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` is configured to run a login shell, you should use a login shell
- if the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` is configured to run a non-login shell, you should use a non-login shell

You can identify this by running `docker inspect` on your container or `docker image inspect` which will give you `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`

Same principle if you first `run` the container then create a shell using `docker exec -it bash [--login]`

For example, using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add bash
RUN echo "export MYVAR=frombashrc" > /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "export MYVAR=fromprofile" > /root/.bash_profile

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

And running:

```
$ docker build . -t mybashimage
$ docker run -it --name bashcontainer mybashimage "bash --login -c 'env && sleep 60'"
HOSTNAME=4aeb776a8c56
MYVAR=fromprofile
...
```

In another shell while container is running:

```
# Running a non-login shell does not have same effect
$ docker exec -it bashcontainer bash
bash-4.4# env
HOSTNAME=5f44398152bf
MYVAR=frombashrc
...

# Running login shell doe
$ docker exec -it bashcontainer bash --login -c 'env'
HOSTNAME=5f44398152bf
MYVAR=fromprofile
...
```

Comment: If you have `jq` installed: `docker image inspect alpine | jq '.[].Config.Cmd'`

Comment: Or something like `docker image inspect alpine --format '{{ .Config.Entrypoint }} {{ .Config.Cmd }}'` in plain Docker (Go template format)

Answer (score 3):

Coming from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237672/280018), one should be able to check whether you are in a login shell with `echo $0`. If there is a `-` prefixed, you are.
A simple example to check for Docker `RUN` directives:

```
$ cat Dockerfile  
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN echo $0

$ docker build --tag foo . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB 
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:18.04 
... 
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:18.04 
 ---> 3556258649b2
Step 2/2 : RUN echo $0
 ---> Running in b3b44e18d744 
/bin/sh 
...
```

As it says `/bin/sh`, I guess it's not a login shell. Please correct me if I'm wrong.